# How do I build my Spring MVC project with maven then run on my vfabric tomcat server, entirely with command line?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

My server runs fine from Eclipse, but I can't get it to run from command line.

Here's what I'm trying, unsuccessfully ("hp-dsat" is the name of my project and also the database name, and project folder that contains pom.xml):

```
# stop server
cd ~/TcServer/
./tcruntime-ctl.sh myserver/ stop

# import clean sql
dropdb hp-dsat
createdb
psql hp-dsat < ~/hp-dsat/src/main/webapp/resources/data.sql

# build project with maven (doing something wrong here?)
cd ~/hp-dsat
mvn compile
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# move the war file to my TcServer
mv -f ~/hp-dsat/target/hp-dsat-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war ~/TcServer/myserver/webapps/ROOT.war

# start the server back up
cd ~/TcServer/
./tcruntime-ctl.sh myserver/ start
```

The server starting, but when I visit myserver.com:8080 or myserver.com:8080/hp-dsat (second one is with the context path) it just returns nothing but a blank page.

The thing is, it works if I build the project in eclipse. I just need to figure out how to do it from command line to make a build script to use on a git hook. The server doesn't have eclipse either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [cargo deploy plugin in maven](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin), and also might want to look at using jenkins, or another CI server aswell.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I tried the following, but it still results in a blank empty page from the server: `mvn clean verify org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run -Dcargo.maven.containerId=tomcat7x -Dcargo.maven.containerUrl=http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.16.zip -Dcargo.servlet.port=8080 -Dmaven.test.skip=true`. Any more ideas?

Comment: debug the problem with the cargo deploy ... lots of examples out there http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/maven-tomcat-deployment-using-cargo